# Passing PHP session variable to AJAX URL

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to pass a session variable into an AJAX loaded page.  Here is the code I am using:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$("#userdetail").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
   url: "userdetail.php?id=<?php $_SESSION['uid']?>",
   success: function(msg){
     $("#results").html(msg);
   }
 });
});
});
```

This is the HTML URL I had working, not sure how to get this into the AJAX call:

```
userdetail.php?id=<?php $_SESSION['uid']?>
```

I should also mention that if I manually pass in the userID it works fine

```
url: "userdetail.php?id=1",
```

Comment: Why are you trying to pass a session ID through a URL string? Most of the time that is a security concern...

Answer (score 0):

If this is what's actually rendering on the page:

```
userdetail.php?id=<?php $_SESSION['uid']?>
```

Then it sounds like your PHP interpreter isn't working on the server.  That should output the actual value (it may need an `echo` or something though, I'm not sure), not the PHP code (which itself should never be output to the client).

Comment: it definitely needs an echo, but that wouldn't explain why it didn't interpret the tags correctly. Bizarre.

Comment: No, it's not that it's actually appearing on the page.  It's just not able to execute the SQL query that it depending on $_SESSION['uid'].  Do I need to set the AJAX call to GET?

Comment: @user547794: If the actual value is being rendered on the page, can you update the question to show the actual JavaScript code block?  If the value is being put in that `url` then you may have to reveal more information.  When you debug `userdetail.php` is the `id` query string value set?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try

```
  url: "userdetail.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['uid']?>",
```

Comment: what URL is called on the log of the server? What do you get if you print_r($_GET) in userdetail.php

Answer (score 0):

Is your file a .js file? 
PHP interpreter doesn't read .js files by default.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by echoing the SESSION variable on the page itself rather than using GET.  Thanks everyone!